# stored procedure mysql input parameter consider as null

Tags: mysql, .net

I have a stored procedure with several input parameters. This is called in many places in the code. Is there a way to not send all the parameters every time I call the stored procedure. AS I wanted them to consider the parameters I have not defiended in the code as null.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Location_search`(
p_DPName varchar(50) ,
p_LTypeId int,
p_FId int ,
p_Query varchar(50),
p_flag int,
p_IsConsided int)
```

begin

Some occurences I only need to input 2 parameters and wanted to consider all the other as NULL.

```
  DBAccess DBA = new DBAccess("Location_search");
  DBA.AddParameter("p_IsConsided ", 1);
  DBA.AddParameter("p_flag ", 0);
```

Is there a way to do this other than defining all the 6 parameters everytime and hard cording them?

Comment: Not there isn't, Consider the call statement it only knows by position what parameters obtain what values.

Comment: my understanding is that this is simply a feature limitation in mysql; "live with it or choose another RDBMS", I suspect